# Xcode5 MPMoviePlayer How do I get it to loop a local video clip?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, video, mpmovieplayer

I'm trying to loop a local video, but I keep having issues. The iphone simulator build will succeed but the video won't play or loop. I'm in the middle of making an App that just plays a video on loop after the LaunchImage. Does it have something to do with the `MPMoviePlayerController`?

Here's the code:
ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize moviePlayer;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSString*thePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ColoredDiamond" ofType:@".mp4"];
    NSURL*theurl=[NSURL fileURLWithPath: thePath];

    self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:theurl];
    [self.moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(40,197,240,160)];
    [self.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
    [self.moviePlayer setShouldAutoplay:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playBackFinished:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayer];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/* - (void) playbackFinished: (NSNotification*) notification{
    NSLog(@"playBackFinished");
    if(moviePlayer){
        [moviePlayer play];
    }
}
*/

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:theurl];
[self.moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(40,197,240,160)];
[self.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];

[self.moviePlayer setRepeatMode:MPMovieRepeatModeOne];

[self.moviePlayer setShouldAutoplay:YES];
[self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];
```

**RepeatMode** determines how the movie player repeats the playback of the movie.

```
@property (nonatomic) MPMovieRepeatMode repeatMode
```

The default value of this property is `MPMovieRepeatModeNone`.

List of available repeat modes,

```
 MPMovieRepeatModeNone,
 MPMovieRepeatModeOne
```

Available in iOS 3.2 and later.

Related Sample Code : [MoviePlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MoviePlayer_iPhone/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007798)

Declared In : `MPMoviePlayerController.h`

Comment: where do I put this into my code? For some reason the moviePlayerController receiver is unknown in my code.. So do I need to create a MPMoviePlayerController.h file in my project?

Comment: I have updated my answer. also please check the sample app that I mentioned in answer.

Comment: when I updated the code with your answer, I received a Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1 at the self.movePlayer = [[MPMovie... line and at the [[NSNotficationCenter... I received an Undeclared selector 'playBackFinished.' Why didn't this compile play the looped .mp4 Ramshad?